# How to Setstate array in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to set state field in array.

Below is my code:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  arrayCheck: [
    isCheck = false
  ]
}
```

I want to get `isCheck` and then set state to true.
How can I set it?

Below is my function setState

```
onCheckBoxChange(isCheck, index, item) {
  this.setState({........});
}
```

Comment: arrays don't have key value pairs, what you need here is an object

Comment: is there only one value? if yes,  why are maintaining the array? it can be used as state directly. dont need to use as array or object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to update a state variable using array you can try this.
First, you need an array of object in state variable and update it like this

```
constructor () {
super();
this.state = {
     arrayCheck: [
        { isCheck : false }
    ]
  }
}
```

then update its value like this

```
onCheckBoxChange(isCheck, index, item) {
   let arrayCheck = [...this.state.arrayCheck]
   arrayCheck[0].isCheck = true
   this.setState({
     arrayCheck
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need `arrayCheck` to be in the `state` object:

```
this.state = {
    arrayCheck = [...]
}
```

Second, I would suggest using an object rather than an array. In array you can only access the index that holds the value.
With an object you may do something like:

```
constructor () {
   super();
   this.state = {
        objectChecks: { // my also just set isCheck on the state
            isCheck: false
        }
   }
}
```

And then when you want to change it:

```
this.setState({objectChecks: {isCheck: true}})
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I need to access isCheck by index.